# Arduino based autoflush

Tags: arduino, autoflush

I want to create an Arduino based auto flush using 3 LEDs and a servo motor. The problem statement is:

1. When the person is detected the first LED should glow and after a second should go low.
2. Till the person is standing the second LED should get high.
3. When the person leaves the second LED should go low and the 3 LED should get high and then go low.

I am stuck at the second part.

```cpp
int trigPin = 12; //triggor pin
int echoPin = 11; // echo pin
long timeperiod;
float cm, distance;
int r = 10, g = 9, rg = 8;
int PreparingToFlush = 0;
void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(9600); //serial port communication
    pinMode(trigPin, OUTPUT); // defining pinmode for trig
    pinMode(echoPin, INPUT); // defining pinmode for echo pin
    pinMode(r, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(g, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(rg, OUTPUT);
}

void loop()
{
    digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW); // sending 10 us pulse
    delayMicroseconds(2);
    digitalWrite(trigPin, HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(10);
    digitalWrite(echoPin, LOW);

    timeperiod = pulseIn(echoPin, HIGH); // integrating pulse

    cm = (timeperiod / 2) / 29.1;
    distance = cm;
    Serial.print("   distance in centimeters=");
    Serial.println(cm);
    delay(1000);
    /* while(distance<=20)
      {
        pinMode(r,HIGH);  //person detected
        delay(1000);
        pinMode(r,LOW);
        delay(1000);
        pinMode(rg,HIGH); //wait
        delay(1000);      //Want delay such that till the person is standing in range of 20cm rg should be high
        pinMode(rg,LOW);
        delay(1000);
         pinMode(g,HIGH);// ready to flush
        delay(1000);
        pinMode(g,LOW);
        delay(1000);
        } 
    while(distance<=20)
    {
       pinMode(r,HIGH);  //person detected
        delay(1000);
        pinMode(r,LOW);
        delay(1000);
        pinMode(rg,HIGH);
    }
       pinMode(rg,LOW);
       delay(1000);
       pinMode(g,HIGH);
       delay(1000);
       pinMode(g,LOW);
       */

    if (distance < 100) { //if distance sensor detects someone
        Serial.println("person detected");
        delay(2000); // wait
        digitalWrite(r, HIGH);
        delay(2000);
        digitalWrite(r, LOW);
        //sensor=analogRead(sensorPin);
        if (distance < 100) { // check again to make sure someone is actually there
            Serial.println("again check");
            digitalWrite(g, HIGH);

            PreparingToFlush = 1;
        }
    }

    if (PreparingToFlush == 1) { //if a person has been detected
        if (distance > 100) { // if the person has now left
            digitalWrite(g, LOW);
            delay(2000);
            digitalWrite(rg, HIGH);
            delay(2000);
            digitalWrite(rg, LOW);
            Serial.println("left");
            //servo1.write(175); FLUSH
            delay(5000);
            //servo1.write(3);

            delay(1000);

            PreparingToFlush = 0; //reset the trigger
        }
    }

    delay(10);
}
```

Comment: What have you done so far? If you simply throw the question like this, others think that you want them to solve your school homework.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve your task by a simple state machine.
1. Define variable "State", it would hold one of the states "wait" (waiting while somebody gets near), "near" (when person moved in to the sensor), "out" (when person moved out), "flush" (when flush is in progress).
2. Create some variable to monitor time passed from some event
3. Move from one state to another when some conditions are satisfied.

Initial:

```cpp
#define STATE_WAIT 0
#define STATE_NEAR 1
#define STATE_OUT 2
#define STATE_FLUSH 3

int state=STATE_WAIT;
int t=0; // Variable to store time for measurement needs
int light_t=0; // Variable to store time for LED switching needs
```

In the loop:

```cpp
switch ( state ) {
//We are in a waiting state
case STATE_WAIT:
    // Measure distance
    ...
    distance = cm;
    // If distance is quite close:
    if (distance < 50)
    {
        if (t == 0)
        {
            t = millis();
        }
        // If distance is quite close for 500 milliseconds:
        // (half of a second) 
        else if (millis() - t > 500)
        {
            // let's switch to STATE_NEAR
            state = STATE_NEAR;
            // remember, when we switched the light on
            light_t = millit();
            // switch the light on
            digitalWrite(YourFirstLedPin, HIGH);
            // peson is standing? Yes, so light the second LED too:
            digitalWrite(YourSecondLedPin, HIGH);
            // reset auxilary time variable:
            t = 0;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        t = 0;
    }
break;
// Person is near the device
case STATE_NEAR:
    // Measure distance
    ...
    distance = cm;

    // if light_t is set, and it was set 1000 msecs ago
    // lets switch off the light
    if (light_t != 0 && millis() - light_t > 1000)
    {
        light_t = 0;
        // switch the first light off
        digitalWrite(YourFirstLedPin, LOW); 
    }

    // If person is far:
    if (distance > 100)
    {
        if (t == 0)
        {
            t = millis();
        }
        // Person is far for 500 milliseconds
        else if (millis() - t > 500)
        {
            // Move to OUT state:
            state = STATE_OUT;
            // Anyway, switch first LED off.
            digitalWrite(YourFirstLedPin, LOW); 
            // switch the second light off
            digitalWrite(YourSecondLedPin, LOW);                 
            // switch the third light on
            digitalWrite(YourThirdLedPin, HIGH);
            // remember when it happend:
            light_t = millis();            
        }
    }

break;
case STATE_OUT:
    // And so on...
    // Wait for 1000 milliseconds, switch off the third light, 
    // execute Flushing mechanism, change to STATE_FLUSH
break;
case STATE_FLUSH:
    // Wait while your flushing is done,
    // Move to STATE_WAIT, and everything will star over.
break;
}
```